# REST convention for exclude

Tags: rest, api

Lets say I have an `organization` table and `role` table and are related with many to many relationship.

1. `/organization` will provide all the organizations.
2. `/organization/1` will provide particular organization.
3. `/organization/1/role` will provide particular organization's role.

Now, what should be the convention to display roles which are **not** in the organization `1`?

Comment: The spelling used in your URI is not (or at least should not be) of importance to your client. The URI as a whole (including any path, matrix or query parameter) is a pointer to a resource. You might think of it in terms of a cache key for retrieving cached representations of a (intermediary) cache. A client will (or should) learn all of the URIs it might use directly from the server itself, so no knowledge or semantical structure is required here. Link relations are used to give the URI some context in regards to how the URI is related to the current representation processed by your client.

Comment: Thanks @RomanVottner So this can be treated using query params?

Comment: It might, it might not. This solely depends on your design. Though as mentioned, this is not important in a REST architecture as the server should provide the clients with all the information needed (including any URIs). I.e. if the server expects certain inputs by the client it should send a form to the client in a representation the client supports rather than expecting the client implementor digging through some external documentation. Content negotiation ensures that both will exchange formats both support. This reduces coupling and allows server to evolve freely without breaking clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Lets say I have an `organization` table and `role` table and are related with a many to many relationship.*

Please bear in mind that REST doesn't have the concept of *tables*. While table a database concern, REST is all about resources.

Fielding [defines](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) *resource* as *any information that can be named*. So, yes, a database table can be seen as a resource, but I understand your API is about the data stored in the tables rather than the tables themselves.

As `/organization` maps to a *collection of organization*, it probably would make more sense to use a *plural noun* such as `/organizations`. Given that REST doesn't say anything about the URI spelling, that's really up to you.

> *What should be the convention to display roles which are not in the organization 1?*

Well, I'm afraid you won't find any standard way (or at least any universally-adopted convention) to represent that in the URI (even in the query string). But let me try to give you my 2 cents anyways.

You could, for example, have a `/roles` endpoint and a query parameter to exclude some company, as shown below:

```
GET /roles?excluding-company=1
```

---

Alternatively, you could separate *collection filtering* from *searching*. That's interesting if your API must support advanced searching. You could consider an endpoint as shown below (I made up the payload):

```
POST /search HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "type": "role",
  "organization": {
    "excluding": [ 1 ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I made something like this `/organization/1/role?exclude=True`. Is it correct?

Comment: @DharanidharReddy REST doesn't say anything about the URI spelling, but your URI doesn't seem to be meaningful for what you intend to used it.